# How can I display equations with long spaces between them?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

How can I create displayed equations with long spaces between them like in the second line of text in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\quad` or even `\qquad` for such long spaces.

For more spacing commands, see some reference, for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode#Reference_guide

Answer (score 0):

I have used `enumitem` with the option `\roman`  to have (i), (ii), etc. labels and I have given a space of `18pt` between the formulas, but you can choose differently.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\setlength\arraycolsep{18pt}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item First roman enumerate
\item If $\theta$ and $\psi$ are formulas, then so are \[\begin{array}{*{5}{l}}
\neg\theta & (\theta\wedge \psi) & (\theta\vee\psi) & (\theta\to\psi) & (\theta\leftrightarrow\psi) \\
\end{array}\]
\item Third roman enumerate
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Peraphs with other math fonts like `MnSymbol` you can obtain the similar symbols.